# Los datos se generan duplicados a partir de 3

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo este codigo para mandar un nombre y apellido a la base de datos dependiendo de la $cantidad de inputs que haya, pero no se porq al poner la $cantidad de inputs en 3 o mas, los datos se mandan duplicados a la base de datos, con 2 y 1 anda bien, pero al tener una $cantidad mayor o igual a 3 los datos se envian duplicados.

```
  <form action="index.php" method="POST" id="formulario">
    <?php
    $cantidad = 3;
    $dato = array();
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $cantidad; $i++) {
      echo '  
 <input type="text" name="nombre' . $i . '" id="apellido" class="campos" placeholder="nombre">
 <input type="text" name="apellido' . $i . '" id="apellido" class="campos" placeholder="apellido"><br>';
    }
    ?>

    <input type="submit" id="boton" name="boton">
    <br>
    <?php

    $dato = array();
    if (isset($_POST['boton'])) {
      for ($i = 1; $i <= $cantidad; $i++) {
        $dato[$i] = array("Nombre" => $_POST['nombre' . $i], "Apellido" => $_POST['apellido' . $i]);
      }
      for ($i = 1; $i < $cantidad; $i++) {
        foreach ($dato as $datos) {
          $query = "INSERT INTO acomp2 values (null,'" . $datos["Nombre"] . "','" . $datos['Apellido'] . "')";
          $me = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
  
        }
      }
    }
    ?>

  </form>
```

Comment: Puedes imprimir $_POST, con print_r($_POST), dentro del if(isset($_POST)). Por otra parte la etiqueta </form> deberías cerrarla después del <br>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que en este bloque estás abriendo bucles anidados sin ninguna necesidad:

```
  for ($i = 1; $i < $cantidad; $i++) {
    foreach ($dato as $datos) {
      $query = "INSERT INTO acomp2 values (null,'" . $datos["Nombre"] . "','" . $datos['Apellido'] . "')";
      $me = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);

    }
  }
```

Tú puedes construir el `INSERT` leyendo directamente el array `$dato` de este modo:

```
    foreach ($dato as $datos) {
      $query = "INSERT INTO acomp2 values (null,'" . $datos["Nombre"] . "','" . $datos['Apellido'] . "')";
      $me = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
    }
```

### Sugerencia de optimización

Dicho eso, tu código puede estructurarse de una forma más simple, creando en los input un array de personas (considera iniciar tus arrays con el índice `0` para que la lectura sea acorde con los estándares de PHP y otros lenguajes).

Significa que si creas los inputs así:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST" id="formulario">

<?php

    $cantidad = 3;
    $dato = array();
    $html="";
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $cantidad; $i++) {
      $html.="<input type=\"text\" name=\"personas[$i][nombre]\" id=\"nombre$i\" class=\"campos\" placeholder=\"nombre\"/><br />";
      $html.="<input type=\"text\" name=\"personas[$i][apellido]\" id=\"apellido$i\" class=\"campos\" placeholder=\"apellido\"/><br />";
    }
    echo $html;
?>
    <input type="submit" id="boton" name="boton">
    </form>
    <br>
<?php
```

Podrás luego hacer una lectura de este modo sin más:

```
if (isset($_POST['boton'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['personas'] as $p){
      $query = "INSERT INTO acomp2 values (null,'$p[nombre]','$p[apellido]')";
      $me = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
    }
}
```

Ten en cuenta que `$_POST` es en sí mismo un array, de modo que si organizas bien el POST (cosa que hicimos al crear los input del formulario) podrás hacer una lectura acorde a ese orden sin necesidad de complicarte la vida creando un nuevo array y además sobrecargando el código.

Aparte de la optimización, hemos corregido aquí un error en cuanto a la construcción del HTML: estabas asignado id repetidos a los elementos, lo cual producirá un HTML erróneo.

Finalmente, quiero señalar que tu consulta SQL es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*, para prevenir este riesgo debes aplicar de forma correcta consultas preparadas. Cuando sea posible, lee sobre este tema para que aprendas como dar seguridad a tu código. No se trata de un problema banal, por instrucciones SQL se puede obtener/modificar/borrar información sensible de la base de datos, se pueden adquirir accesos a áreas protegidas y en muchos casos se puede incluso acceder  al sistema de archivos e instalarte programas maliciosos.